# Extract links from specific div - Rvest

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the links from a specific class from a website. However, there is a empty dataset when I do that.

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

links_avai <- paste0("https://avai.com.br/page", seq(from = 1, to = 2)) %>%
  map(. %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="gdlr-blog-title"]') %>%
        html_attr("href"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
links_avai <- paste0("https://avai.com.br/page", seq(from = 1, to = 2)) %>%
  map(. %>%
        read_html() %>%
        html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="gdlr-blog-title"]') %>%
        html_nodes("a") %>%
        html_attr("href"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).